# Why do we delete window.self?

Tags: javascript, browser, sails.js

I was checking ejs layout code of sails.js and saw the line that says `delete window.self`

```
<% /* Delete the global `self` to help avoid client-side bugs.
(see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) */ %>

<script>delete window.self;</script>
```

I tried searching for to find an answer of why would we delete the window.self but could not find an answer. What is the rationale behind adding this line?

Edit:
The code exist at line no. 137 here: https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/views/layouts/layout.ejs

Comment: I don't see it mentioned anywhere else. If no one knows, maybe ask whoever added that line? (it doesn't sound like a normal good thing to do)

Comment: If I had to guess it's done to "help avoid client-side bugs".  There is also an attached link explaining it further...  Not sure what the client-side bugs are but it most likely has to do with how browsers support self.

Comment: @matthew ... but ... that link is dead and [Window.self](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/self) doesn't contain any hint on why it is bad.

Comment: That link is alive and well, your link even links right back to it haha.  And while it doesn't expressly say why it is bad, it states that window.self and window are interchangeable.  From there you can then get to the logic that the current top answer has, which is that the variable is pointless and clogs up the global namespace.

Comment: Please have a look at line number 137 in the following code: https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/views/layouts/layout.ejs

Answer (score 5):

The only explanation that would make sense to me would be:

To [access the correct "this" inside a callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback) it is common practice to store a `self` reference:

```
 var self = this;
onSomething(function() {
  self.doSomething();
});
```

Now imagine someone forgot the first line, then `self.doSomething()` would say "doSomething" is not a function which is certainly missleading. If `window.self` gets deleted it'll say `self` is not defined, which is way more helpful.

... however it would be better to not name it `self` here...

Comment: Or to use more modern practices like passing an arrow function and allowing a transpiler to make it backwards compatible...

Comment: Can you please look at the ref in line no. 137 in the code: https://github.com/mikermcneil/ration/blob/master/views/layouts/layout.ejs